# What Can Access "App Settings Key Values"?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In an Microsoft Azure Web App Service under `Application Settings`, there are Key-Value pair options within the option `App Settings`.  If a developer has PHP or Python files in multiple directories, which of these directories and (or) files would have access to these key-value pairs.

**Example:**

Suppose the developer has the following key value pair settings in `App Settings`:

Key: `$variableString` | Value: `"My first example string."`

Key: `$variableNumber` | Value: `1000`

**PHP files:**

`site\wwwroot\index.php`

`site\wwwroot\folderone\pageone.php`

`site\wwwroot\folderone\pagetwo.php`

`site\wwwroot\foldertwo\page.php`

Would all these files have access to these variables, or would these files need to have a reference (and where?) to where these key-value pairs would be saved like in each PHP file with an `include` pointer to the `App Settings` file (Azure doesn't show this becomes a file)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will be available as environment variables so it doesn't matter where the file is.

If you set an app setting with key ITEM_COUNT and value 15, you could use:

```
$item_count = getenv('ITEM_COUNT');
```

Or:

```
$item_count = getenv('APPSETTING_ITEM_COUNT');
```

And $item_count would contain the string "15".

Answer (score 2):

Anything that can access environment variables can access those, as those are environment variables. So python would be able, not sure about php, since I know nothing about it, but pretty sure it could.

In my code I just use this:

> "{0}-{1}".format(os.getenv('LOCATION'), os.getenv('COMPUTERNAME'))

Comment: So the page `site\wwwroot\folderone\pageone.php` should be able to use the string `$variableString` if I were to code `echo $variableString`.

Comment: as I said, I'm no php expert, but this seems relevant: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php  
$var = getenv('variableString');