# Providing DB credentials via environment and not hard coded

Tags: php, sql, azure, pdo

I am creating a web application and need to connect to a MySQL database. I am currently using PHP 7.3. I am connecting to the SQL database using PDO standard way (`new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS)`) but I have been told the following statement:

> Database credentials should be coming from the environment and not be hard-coded in the source code.

However, I am unsure how to do this.

Currently, the application is being hosted on a Linux server but is being migrated to an Azure server. But before we can migrate it, they would like me to change the SQL credential configuration as stated above.

I am current using the class provided in the PHP documentation comments found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#93178).

Comment: You could use [this](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) library and store credentials in a .env file

Answer (score 0):

Storing secrets in web applications is complex, but most languages/frameworks have ways of doing it.

In PHP, one way you could do it is store the information in environment variables, which you can then [retrieve at run time.](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643130/using-environment-variables-in-php) For instance, you could use

```
$DB_DSN = $_SERVER["DB_DSN"];
$DB_USER = $_SERVER["DB_USER"];
$DB_PASS = $_SERVER["DB_PASS"];
```

You can set these environment variables [using the App Settings tab in Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Fcontainers%2Ftoc.json#configure-app-settings).

Each environment (development machines, test servers, production servers) could then have those environment variables set differently.

There's even a [library](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) to help you with this.

Comment: This article is too localized to some internet service provider and doesn't explain how to implement it of your own, which, I believe, is asked here, In other words, it doesn't explain, how DB_DSN makes it into  $_SERVER

Comment: That's a reasonable comment - I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current Linux installation is using Apache as a web-server, you can configure environment variables in its configuration files (httpd.conf or .htaccess) like this

```
SetEnv DB_USER whatever
```

In case its Nginx, it will be

```
fastcgi_param DB_USER whatever;
```

After that, it will be possible to access such values using `$_ENV` array like this

```
new PDO($dsn, $_ENV['DB_USER'], $_ENV['DB_PASS']);
```

(note that I would avoid storing entire DSN in the envieonment as it's too localized to PDO. Better to store the usual parameters like DB_HOST and DB_NAME and then conjure DSN from them)

Given Azure is using neither, you will have to configure such variables Windows-way - in a some GUI application as explained in this answer [What Can Access "App Settings Key Values"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531496/what-can-access-app-settings-key-values)

Of course, the process should be repeated for all instances where the code is run, on your local dev server for example.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to do this, none of them is easy. However, a quick and easy approach is to save the credentials in an external file on the server, let the php get the credentials from it and secure it with htaccess.

## 1. Prepare your files :-

1. Create a folder on the server called "_secure".
2. Create a file under "_secure" called "creds.ini" containing `username|password`.
3. Create a file under "_secure" called ".htaccess".

## 2. Secure your credentials :-

Inside your ".htaccess" file, add the following text :-

```
# Deny access to .htaccess
<Files .htaccess>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Disable directory browsing 
Options -Indexes

# Deny access to files with extensions .ini
<FilesMatch "\.(ini)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

## 3. Integrate with PHP :

Inside your php, use the following code :-

```
$creds = explode('|', file_get_contents("creds.ini"));
new PDO(DB_DSN, $creds[0], $creds[1]);
```

You have to customize the names and the php code according to your usage, these are just sample codes and names.

Comment: The protection will never work and will actually expose the credentials to anyone as Azure doesn't recognize .htaccess

Comment: Well, he can still skip this step and have the approach but with no secure way, the best approach is the environment variables which he is having problem implementing.

Comment: I believe the security is the main concern here